# List collection used by multiple threads(clients)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Asp Net, and a list collection. Every client which will connect in server, will read this list. If his ID-Name exist in list,it will modify or remove the list row where ID-Name is equal, else if the ID-Name is not exist it will add his ID-Name.
The only fuctions which i will use is

```
Add
Any
ForEach.List
RemoveAll
```

I don't know if list collection is good approach. I just want a quick process on server, avoiding to read or write into a database.

```
 public class Customers
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }

    List<Customers> myCustomers = new List<Customers>();
    // POST: api/Customers
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {

        //read incoming request 
        if (myCustomers.Any(x => x.CustomerName == "IncomingName"))
            myCustomers.RemoveAll(x => x.CustomerName == "IncomingName");

        else
            myCustomers.Add(new Customers { CustomerID = 1, CustomerName = "IncomingName" });

    }
}
```

Maximum requests on server will be up to 2000.
Please let me know if there is better aproach for what i need. I know that list is not safe thread. Is there any way to handle this actions?
Am i safe if i will use lock in list?

Comment: There is no db? When appliaction restrat you loose all your Cust ?

Comment: Nο there is db. But before i will insert into db, i want to make simple checks inside my apllication. Keeping db less busy. Also i don't need db too often. Imagine that one user will send a request and another user will try to read and answer this request. So i beleive that it will be time consuming insert in db and then to read again for answering in new user. Something at low level of a chat method.

Comment: How is that list defined/loaded? If it's just a field of your controller it's going to be recreated on each request. You'd have to find a way to persist it between requests And share it between users of your app. What you've shown wouldn't suffer any multi threading issues because each request would have their own (different) copy.

Comment: I can create a public static List inside a class. And then controller redericting from there. With this way i will not lose my data in each request. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at:

- `BlockingCollection`
- `ConcurrentBag`

At its simplest, you can use an object variable and do a `lock(object)` for modify operations.

You can also look at **not** using linq as it comes with its own overheads and is slow and stick to for loops or foreach loops.

Comment: Is it better for looking in database for each request? instead of looking in a list?

Answer (score 0):

**Data Storage-**

You will need to store this information in some kind of database or make your application singleton because you will loose all the data stored in the particular variable at the end of request. making your application singleton may impact the performance and other factors significantly.

NoSQL database can be used to store this kind of information if you want to reduce the load from the application database.

**Thread Safety -**

No thread safety mechanism is required until and unless multiple threads can access same data simultaneously. It will make sense to implement thread safety only if multiple clients are accessing same instance of service.

For example - In case of singleton, all clients access the same instance and thread safety is mandatory in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The C# List generic supports thread safety by using the `Synchronized` property, but there are also thread safe versions of several other collections such as dictionaries, which when performing the kind of operation you're describing might be of some use.

Here is an article that describes the threadsafe primitives, and has some links to the more specific types.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

ConcurrentDictionary has some nice threadsafe methods such as `GetOrAdd` and `AddOrUpdate` which depending on your application may be of some use. You could also just use a `lock(myCustomers){ ... }` block which might be good enough for your purpose.